# Laravel blade template is not working - Call to undefined function Illuminate\View\Compilers\token_get_all()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I just installed Laravel 4.2.7 and started to have some problems compiling blade templates.

So Laravel comes with this function in the `HomeController`

```
public function showWelcome()
{
    return View::make('hello');
}
```

I decided to add some variables to the hello view by adding this:

```
public function showWelcome()
{
    $data['test'] = 'hello world!';
    return View::make('hello', $data);
}
```

And... change the file name from `hello.php` to `hello.blade.php` because i want to print out the variable `test`.

Once I refresh the default page that Laravel ships with the 'You have arrived' page it gives me an exception:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException thrown with message "Call to undefined function Illuminate\View\Compilers\token_get_all()"

Stacktrace:
#1 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException in /Applications/AMPPS/www/weinternship/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php:118
#0 Illuminate\Exception\Handler:handleShutdown in <#unknown>:0
```

I have worked with Laravel 4.1.28 and never ran into this problem before. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT

in my contents of the hello.blade.php

i just inserted the {{$test}} within the `<div class="welcome'></div>`

Comment: Add the contents of `hello.blade.php` to the question

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: Tried running PHP 5.4 and 5.5 it still doesnt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version of php was not compiled with tokenizer.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.tokenizer.php

You may be running an old version of PHP. these functions were introduced in PHP 4.2.0:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php

Comment: i tried both PHP version 5.4 and 5.5, it still doesn't work :(

Comment: try running function_exists('token_get_all')

if it return false that is your problem and something is wrong with your php install

Comment: Looks like you need to reinstall php. If you are on a mac I suggest using Homebrew: http://brew.sh/ if you are on Windows I suggest finding a package manager

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error and on opening of php.ini file, I have found that tokenizer extension was disabled.

```
extension=tokenizer.so
```

Enabled it, restarted apache and it worked.

P.S I was getting Open ssl error too and I enabled that extension also:

```
extension=openssl.so
```